# How to safely install a window AC unit?

Tags: air-conditioning, safety

I have a standard air conditioner.  I have just dropped it into the window and slammed the window closed.  I am just a bit concerned that If there were high winds or an earthquake the unit could drop out of the window.  Is this dangerous?  I live on the third floor so if it fell out of the window it could easily kill somebody.

I looked on youtube and it looks like the standard way to install an AC unit is to just open the window put it in and close the window again.  This seems very minimal.  Any other things to consider?

[image]

Comment: This [Answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/6433/33) might be useful.

Comment: This [Answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14656/33) might also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Measure from the top of the bottom sash to the top of the window casing. Get two pieces of wood about 2" by 2" and long enough to reach from the sash to the top of the casing. Cut them long enough to be a tight fit. With the wood wedged in the a/c unit should be secure. This also works on first floor units where added security is a factor as the window cannot be easily opened from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

There are usually a couple of screw holes in the angle bracket that is welded to the top of the A/C. These are for installing a couple of wood screws into the sash to hold it shut against the top of the A/C unit.

This is obviously a method that damages the sash so is not a good option for many people. In that case, the cut to length wood stops is a very good option.