# Can I vent a bathroom fan through an attic window?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, venting

Would venting a bathroom exhaust fan into the attic and through the attic window cause any problems?  I was thinking this would prevent cutting a hole in the roof or the soffit.  My thought was to insert the vent through a pane of glass.    The window is old and that attic is large(it could actually be a room).  Also, should the windows in an attic be well air tight?

Answer (score 2):

This could be an option, as long as a few conditions are met.

## There should be a damper

A damper will prevent outside air from entering the exhaust pipe, traveling down the length and entering the conditioned space. Most exhaust vent covers are designed in such a way, so that even on windy days the exhaust can still be exhausted.  If you just have a pipe pointing to the outside, it's possible the outside air pressure can overcome the exhaust air pressure preventing the exhaust from exhausting.

## There shouldn't be a way for the exhaust to reenter the building

If you simply close the window on a pipe that does not completely fill the opening, it's very likely that air pressure differences will force the exhausted air right back in the window.  You'll want to devise a way to prevent the exhausted air from reentering the building. [This other answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/6433/33) illustrates a way to install the vent, while blocking the entire window opening.

Comment: With the use of a damper this sounds like a possible solution.  Additional recommendations are also appreciated.  I didn't realize how tricky venting through the attic could be!