# Living near a highway in SoCal with no standard windows - how to install A/C?

Tags: hvac, windows, air-conditioning, exhaust-fan, cooling

I have an air purifier and keeping all windows/doors closed is going to be a must.  But the humidity and temperature are issues now.  I can get a dehumidifier but then I'm left with the temperature problem - I like a cool 68F.  It seems like my options are:

- **Portable A/C** with some kind of tube - I haven't seen any on Amazon that have good reviews though.  I also don't know where I would go about installing the exhaust tube.
- **In-window AC** - I'd be fine with this if it fit a standard outlet however none of my windows seem compatible with this setup (see below for photos).
- **Evaporative cooler** - this seems nice in theory but I'm in SoCal where humidity can be an issue.  I also haven't seen any with promising consumer reviews.
- **Ductless** - I like this but... $$$

Am I missing any options?  How would you go about keeping your air crisp, clean, and cool in my situation?

Pics of my windows:

BATHROOM - one little window, sliding:

[image]

KITCHEN - two windows, sliding:

[image]

BEDROOM - one window, sliding:

[image]

And then I have a sliding door in my living room.

I consider myself to be handy-capable - enough so to remove windows and such.  I just repainted my place, replaced all outlets/switches, installed a fan etc so I'm comfortable making modifications as needed but I'd like to keep costs (time, money) as low as possible.

Comment: "It's not the heat, it's the humidity!" *said no Angelino, ever*. Your trouble is too little humidity, and that makes evaporative coolers work at peak performance.

Comment: Possible a through-the-wall unit.

Comment: I had a house years ago with crank-out windows. We were able to find a vertical style air conditioner that fit one of the windows. A vertical style AC unit will be more expensive but they are made to fit your sliding style windows and some crank-out windows.

Comment: This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/6433/33) might be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think the sliders can't be used? The area above the AC unit can be sealed with a piece of rigid insulation board cut to size .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, casement window air conditioners are available.

The portable units work okay.  Obviously they eat some floor space.  You may have to empty the condensate that collects.  You have to run a dryer type hose to exhaust hot air.  The units usually come with a mounting bracket that go in a window, but somehow these are always useless plastic junk.  However it's very easy to make a plywood window bracket for the hose.  It's not that hard to install a permanent dryer vent if you'll use the same unit in the same window every year.

You can buy air conditioners that are made to install in a permanent wall penetration, search for "through-wall air conditioner" - they usually have a sheet metal box that stays in place year round.  There is obviously some carpentry involved but it's not too difficult.  If you can place them below a window, usually you don't have to install a header over the opening.  If you don't want to DIY it, it's not something for a handyman, but an easy job for a carpenter.

I think the ductless will be your best option - they are a lot more money, but popular for good reasons and although definitely advanced DIY, DIY-able.

- Flexible options for location of indoor units
- Efficient electric heat for moderate climates
- Quiet
- No annual installation / removal
- No cords
- No compromise of security (break ins)
- No drafts around window units
- Adds value to home

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a casement window unit that fits both sliding windows and casement windows. Just enter the term "casement window air conditioners". Also inquire about an installation kit that will fill in the space above the unit to keep out the outside air.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: split system. 
Won't be like whole-house but if you put splits in strategical points as:

- night-zone corridor
- living room

And leaving the doors open so it will do it's job.
3 splits won't be too expensive too. I paid my two split (3.6 thermal-kW each) system about 3000€, about 10 years ago, installation included.

I'm in a 120 m^2 flat, not well insulated, I'm in a very moisty area (Po Valley). In summer we reach quite often 38°C and moisture is around 95% (at least at night).

Mine is a Mitsubishi system.

Comment: That price sounds a little high but at 10 years ago this was very new technology. There are more options today and the with the different brands has brought the price down.