# Venting a portable AC with a mesh window

Tags: air-conditioning

We bought a portable AC. Unfortunately, our windows to the outside only open a certain amount and we don’t have the type of window shown in the video here where we can open it up and close (see picture) so we can’t attach the accessory to vent the hot air out in the way they describe.

As a result, we try to vent the air out in the way shown in the picture but we still feel hot air come back through the mesh window. And bc our window doesn’t open up all the way, we can’t get the hose to point directly outside.

We'd prefer not to do what was outlined here and build a new seal bc we want to be able to see the from that window and sometimes just take the AC hose out entirely. [How do I install a portable air conditioning unit in a large sliding window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/how-do-i-install-a-portable-air-conditioning-unit-in-a-large-sliding-window?rq=1)

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0d1bidUO1sLGA41Rd_Uksc1yQ

Answer (score 2):

This type of window is called a casement window. You need a "casement window AC vent kit" which uses flexible plastic shaped in a wedge to provide a vent hole.

Comment: We tried that but these things are quite ugly and my wife doesn’t want it. :(. We’re looking for something to hose the hot air further past the window